# Checking Sucsessfull Validation of Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller, data-annotations

I have a C# ViewModel, specifying data annotations for automatic validation.
I render the View in Razor code.
I need to check in javascript, client side, if the ALL validations went through, or not.

I Have tried to catch the Submit event of the form. This worked, but is not fired after the validation completed. I recon I need to check for a state, or listen for some event that will fire when validation succeeded.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Before Fade");
        $("#LoaderSpinner").fadeOut('hidden');
    });

    $("#HelloForm").submit(function () {
        alert('SUBMITTED THE FORM');
        // Here i need to check if the form validated before activating the spinner
        $("#LoaderSpinner").fadeIn();
    });

</script>
```

A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Web API or ASP.NET MVC for your controllers?

Comment: I am using MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
if($("form").valid()){
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('form').submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    if($form.valid()) {
        //do stuff here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#HelloForm").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($("#HelloForm").valid()) {
        $(this).off('submit').submit();
    }
});
```